# Why does my git clone show just a blank page?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a Git repository on my local computer, that is *cloned* onto a shared server. On my local computer everything works fine, but on the shared server I have a blank page.

I see all the code in my FTP client and I get the git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

On my local computer I have the same message, so the source are up-to-date.

Now the strange thing: On my local computer I can see my website. But on my server it is just a blank page. How is this possible? Could this have something to do with the htaccess? The code should be exactly the same.

Technical information: Local computer is Mac OSX. Shared Server is Linux System. I have installed Symfony framework

Comment: Even if the code is the same, perhaps you have some missing dependencies (like Composer in php)? Or perhaps your Apache configuration doesn't allow .htaccess. If it works on you machine and not on your server, there is a difference between your two environments. Could you provide more informations about your environments?

Comment: @AnthonyB yeah. But I cannot install composer on my shared host. I am not able to install anything.

Comment: @AnthonyB added more technical information

Comment: If your project needs some Composer packages, it won't work without them. In case you cannot install Composer, copy/paste your `vendor/` directory onto the server, through FTP for example.

Comment: @AnthonyB Indeed. The vendor/ folder was not copied.. Strange. I thought "clone" is an exact clone

Comment: The `vendor/` directory should not be commited, it's in the Symfony's `.gitignore`. Because usually during the deployment process we run `composer install`. In your case if you really can't install it, you'll have to copy/paste it when you update your dependencies.

Comment: It is. But maybe your vendor folder is ignored and was not committed? That's usually a common practice for things, which are generated or handled by package managers.

Comment: Now I see. I copy the vendor folder right now. When finished I let you know if it worked

Comment: Yes, this was the reason. Copying the .gitignore folders solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Symfony framework, but as it was said in comments on your shared server you don't have [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install dependencies.
The [Symfony's .gitignore](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/.gitignore) ignores the `vendor/` directory because usually the dependencies during the deployment process by executing `composer install`.

In your case, if you haven't Composer on your shared server, you can copy/paste your `vendor/` directory from your PC onto your server.
Do not forget to copy/paste it again when you update your dependencies.

**The easier approach would be to have Composer on your server to execute `composer install` each time you push your project onto your server.**